# In Hulk (2003) why did one person survive but another didn't?

Tags: the-incredible-hulk, marvel, hulk-2003

At the end of the movie when

> David was trying to absorb the life from Bruce and the military airplane dropped a bomb on them, afterwards it was shown Bruce was still alive but did David die?

I looked it up on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulk_%28film%29#Plot) and it has

> David finds that the Hulk's energy is too much for him to handle and he is killed by an army missile at the height of his weakness

So how come the Hulk's power was too much for him? If he had absorbed a lot of the Hulk's power wouldn't that mean the Hulk was weak too and should've been killed by the bomb?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Official Novelisation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345459679) it was a mixture of factors.

- David Banner absorbed the Hulk's power. He was able to cope, but only just and at the cost of merging with the Hulk entity.
- Bruce Banner (as junior partner in the merger) was simply thrown out of the gestalt entity and fell into the water, where he was protected from the explosion. Later he emerged and went into hiding.
- When the nuke went off, it gave David Banner too much power and he overloaded and died.
- Bruce's power drain proved to be only temporary. After a period, his Hulk form reasserted itself (as we seen in the final scene in the Amazon).

> The Hulk seemed to dissolve, but Bruce Banner could be glimpsed
>   briefly inside the falling shape as it dropped into the lake. His
>   father, victorious, towered above the mountains. He saw on the horizon
>   a fleet of puny Stealth fighters and jets making their way toward him,
>   and he laughed and laughed, and his laughter resounded like thunder.
>
> Then he paused, and looked down at his stomach. Swirling energy
>   radiated into his whole body making it bigger, bigger. He thrashed
>   about, looking for his son or the Hulk, and began to scowl.
>
> “*You!*” he shouted to no one. “*The reaction—you tricked me! Take it
>   back! It’s not stopping!*”
>
> Nor was it. It spun out of control, the different energies colliding,
>   his body absorbing everything, the moonlight, the air, the wind, and
>   when there was nothing else, his body—seeking new energy sources—found
>   the largest one around: itself. His body literally began to devour
>   itself, the effect flowing from the middle and surging outward, and as
>   the father clutched at himself and screamed and howled, a voice
>   sounded in his head, and it might have been his own, but it sounded
>   like his son’s. And the words—the parting words from his
>   offspring—burned into his fevered consciousness.
>
> *. . . things fall apart . . . the center cannot hold . . .*
>
> David Banner stumbled to the top of the mountain, and this time he
>   didn’t notice the fighters swiftly approaching from behind.
>
> And in the far, far distance, Thunderbolt Ross looked at his daughter
>   as he gave the final order. “*Gentlemen, release.*”
>
> The thermonuclear missile took off from one of the planes, heading
>   straight for the father who continued to grow and distend in an agony
>   of energy. Something warned him at the last moment, and he turned and
>   saw it coming. For a half-second a grin split his face as he
>   anticipated more energy to absorb, but then he realized, Too much! Too
>   much!
>
> *. . . the center cannot hold. Best wishes from this rough beast . . .*
>
> The missile struck him and his center shredded and blew apart, unable
>   to contain it, as a massive explosion—an explosion evocative of that
>   which had haunted Bruce and Betty’s dreams for as long as they could
>   remember—engulfed the sky.

Comment: "fell into the water, where he was protected from the explosion" wasn't Bruce and David already in the water as David was trying to drown/freeze Bruce in it when the bomb hit?

Comment: @Celeritas - "*David Banner stumbled to the top of the mountain"*

Answer (score 0):

My other theory to add to this is that when Hulk started to give his old man energy, Hulk was at his 15ft stage because as you know, this Hulk only grew in height as well as power. So, this was probably included with the energy.

Finally, I also think that if Hulk stayed at his 9ft stage, David probably would've been able to cope with Hulk's energy.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is this a personal theory, or do you have some evidence to support this?

Answer (score 0):

what ended up happening even though david try to absorb hulk power for himself what he doesn't know is that hulk power in the anglee movie is powered by his emotional trauma which according to betty physical trauma is finite but emotional trauma  is like a chain reaction that goes on an on an on basically saying emotional trauma has no limit sense hulk is the embodiment of not only his mutated DNA But also the emotional trauma he had when he was a child so when hulk said take it all its bruce finally lets go let his rage for his father out everything he's repressed up until this point once bruce unleash

it its beyond what david can handle as said in the film bruce emotional trauma has no limit and this left david banner vulnerable to the nuke that coming his way bruce was able survive this due being in the water