# How is that a fuel air bomb could hurt Hulk, but a nuclear bomb didn't kill him?

Tags: marvel, hulk-2003

In *Hulk* (2003), Hulk is hit, but not directly, by an apparently Fuel Air Bomb, I believe they are also called MOAB (Mother of All Bombs). If I understand correctly, these bombs have yields measured in tons of TNT. The bomb didn't directly hit him, but the blast reached him and wounded him, to the extent that it took a few seconds to regenerate.

Then, when battling David, who had the ability to absorb energy, a nuclear bomb is dropped over them. Nuclear bombs have yields measured in kilotons (or megatons) meaning they should be thousands of times more powerful. Also they take microseconds to explode, meaning they couldn't give Hulk the time to regenerate the wounds (which took a few seconds with the Fuel Air Bomb)

Was David still alive and absorbed the energy of the bomb or something?
How is that a fuel air bomb could hurt Hulk, but a nuclear bomb didn't kill him?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [In Hulk (2003) why did one person survive but another didn't?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/82375/3804)

Comment: @AncientSwordRage question about the same scene but for different reasons

Comment: If the explanation in the answer isn't what you're after, can you edit the question here to explain what's missing, I'll happily withdraw the vtc.